# Fix vanishing mouse cursor on Ubuntu 20.04 running on 2009 27" iMac

Tags: gnome, cursor

I have Ubuntu desktop 20.04 running on a 2009 27" iMac. Strangely from time to time during normal use the mouse cursor vanishes, and the only way to get it back is to go into Universal Access settings and set the cursor size to "largest". If I then try to set it to anything smaller it becomes invisible again. Set it to largest - it comes back.

The mouse still actually works - e.g. if I right click the desktop the context menu appears and if I move the mouse and repeat it appears somewhere else, also clicking UI components works.

As an experiment I have tried setting the cursor size on using the terminal by changing

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size [sizeInPixels]`

It consistently vanishes <= 80 and re-appears >= 81

Not sure what to try next and unfortunately I cant seem to find any solutions online. Any suggestions on where to look?

Cheers!
NFV

Comment: I've had weird mouse cursor issues until I tried a mouse theme that worked consistently.

Comment: Hello! Did you solve? I have a touch screen and the pointer reappears when I touch the screen but it's really annoying.

Comment: Sorry I have still not managed to solve this annoying problem!